# How do I point a domain name registered with AWS to a website on a non-AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

How do I point a domain name registered with AWS to a Django website on heroku?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Comment: Thanks this was helpful in getting me started, but on AWS I get that I'm supposed to put the DNS target Heroku gives me in the Route 53 Name field and choose CNAME, but I don't understand what I put in Value field or where to get it. Where do I get my IPv4 address?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Route 53 is a DNS service just like any other DNS service.

You would create either:

- A `CNAME` record, pointing to the DNS name of your external site, or
- An `A` record, pointing to the IP address of your external site